# A question on linear maps itself

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Here is just a sample problem.

Suppose that $V$ is finite dimensional and $S, T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Prove that $ST = I$ if and only if $TS = I$

Proof : Suppose that $ST = I$. The identity map $I$ is invertible, so by problem 3.22 both $S$ and $T$ are invertible. Multiply $ST = I$ on the right by $T^{−1}$ to get $S = T^{−1}$. We then have $TT^{−1} = TS = I$. Of course the implication $TS = I$ implies $ST = I$ follows by reversing
the roles of $S$ and $T$.

My question : As of my understanding of linear maps, they are functions that map vectors from one vector space to another and function composition may not be commutative, i.e $f \circ g \neq g \circ f$. I am confused on to why they can treat the function as some sort of matrix, multiplying to the left or right sides of functions.

Am I misunderstanding the concept of linear maps or am I missing alternate definitions ?

Thank you for your help, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ST = I$ is an abbreviation for $S \circ T = I$. In this case, by multiplying on the right by $T^{-1}$, they mean
$$(\star) \hspace{0.7cm} (S \circ T) \circ T^{-1} = I \circ T^{-1}. $$
Notice that $S, T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, so both $S \circ T$ and $T \circ S$ are defined. Moreover, the condition that $S \circ T = I$ (or $T \circ S = I$) implies that both $S$ and $T$ are invertible, so their inverses $S^{-1}$ and $T^{-1}$ are also linear maps from $V$ to $V$. This makes the composition in $(\star)$ legitimate.

This result is saying that for linear maps from a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ to itself, it is enough to have either $S \circ T = I$ or $T \circ S = I$ to deduce the other.

---

On the other hand, there is a relation between composition of linear maps and matrix multiplication. Suppose that $U, V, W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces and choose a basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $U$, a basis $\mathcal{E}$ for $V$, and a basis $\mathcal{D}$ for $W$. If $T: U \rightarrow V$ and $S: V \rightarrow W$ are linear maps, then $S \circ T$ is a linear map from $U$ to $W$, and we can calculate its matrix with respect to the bases of $U$ and $W$ via matrix multiplication:
$$ M_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{D}}( S \circ T) = M_{\mathcal{E}}^{\mathcal{D}}( S ) M_{\mathcal{B}}^{\mathcal{E}}( T ), $$
so the matrix of $S \circ T$ is the product of the matrices of $S$ and $T$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll point out some basic facts about linear maps that might be helpful.

Consider some real matrix $A$. It's easy to verify that the function $x \mapsto Ax$ is a linear map. On the other hand it's possible to show that given *any* linear map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, there is some matrix $A$ such that $f(x) = Ax$. In other words, matrices and linear maps are two aspects of the same thing.

About the matrix product: Consider two linear maps $f$ and $g$. Let $A$ and $B$ the corresponding matrices. What's the matrix of $f \circ g$? Well it's the product matrix $A B$. Why? Well ever wonder why matrix product is defined in such a weird way? The whole point in defining it that way is to make $AB$ correspond to $f \circ g$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a good explanation but since $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb K$ of finite dimension, say , $n$ , we can always view $L(V)$ as matrix algebra $M_n(\mathbb K)$.

The isomorphism is constructed by calculating $f(v_j)$ where $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is the basis of $V$, and decomposing them into $f(v_j)=a_{1j}v_1+...+a_{nj}v_n$. Then $(a_{ij})_{i,j}$ is the matrix form of $f$.

The only place where finite dimensional condition is used is "The identity map I is invertible, so by problem 3.22 both S and T are invertible" and the rest of the proof has nothing to do with it. And, whether $f\circ g=g\circ f$ or not, multiplying on both sides should preserve equality (associativity may be needed).

Comment: Are you under the impression that the words "left" and "right" apply only to matrices?  They are not "treating the function as some sort of matrix" they are simply not ASSUMING that application of functions is commutative.

Comment: @user247327 Well...... I said whether f∘g=g∘f or not, multiplying on both sides should preserve equality. The reason I write about matrix is because it is asked in the question that why they can treat the function as some sort of matrix.